# Acessar objetos html no código em asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, webforms

Tenho uma página que contem objetos *asp.net* e html.

Como faço para acessar objetos html do design no .cs com `C#` ?

Comment: Você está usando MVC ou WebForms? No WebForms é possível, já no MVC você tem que manipular os elementos do HTML usando JavaScript ou renderizando novamente no servidor.

Comment: Estou usando webforms mesmo. Como faço para conseguir acessar e trabalhar com ele ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para acessar um objeto HTML através do código C#, você deve adicionar os atributos `id` e `runat="server"` no elemento HTML que você deseja acessar.

Feito isso, o elemento HTML está disponível para ser acessado via C# usando o ID.

Comment: É isso, Obrigado Renato.

Comment: Você poderia me tirar outra duvida ?
Tenho uma gridview nesta mesma página, que estou usando TemplateField para exibir o campo data, e quero exibir no formato dd/MM/yyyy, porem ele está exibindo como datetime. Já coloquei {0:dd/MM/yyyy} e não funciona. Pode me ajudar ?